# Pymongo Cursor to Dataframe taking long time

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am using Mongodb Database to store data, and while I query data from the DB, it gives the output in 'pymongo cursor' type, which I need to convert to Dataframe. However, I have tried 2 methods, but they are taking 2-4 seconds to do it(even for as less as 1 record). Is there a way of faster conversion to dataframe?

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pymongo import MongoClient

client=MongoClient("Server Connection String", username = 'username', password='password')

db=client["DB_Name"]
collection=db['Table_Name']

data=collection.find({}).limit(1)

#Method 1 of Conversion of pymongo cursor to dataframe

my_data = list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()), data))

result = np.array(my_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

#Method 2 of Conversion of pymongo cursor to dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(list(data))
```

Comment: When you are timing this, are you including the time it takes to establish the initial connection to the database? There's no timing code shared in the snippet so there is no way to tell at the moment. Establishing the connection usually requires a couple of round trips across the network and may be dominating the time from your tests.

Comment: You should use `find_one` rather than `find` with a limit. Because you are only processing one document the `map()` is not required. You convert the data to a numpy array and then you convert that data to a dataFrame. All this takes time. Is the `table_name` field indexed? Without an index you will do a full collection scan and that is very time-consuming.